# How to use dataset.map() method with Tensorflow 2 and nested lists?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to apply the [tf.data.Dataset.map](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?hl=en&version=stable#map) method to my dataset in the context of image captioning using Tensorflow 2.

Running the following code

```
def map_func(img_name, cap_train, target):
  img_tensor = np.load(img_name+'.npy')
  return img_tensor, cap_train, target

train = [
  [
    'image_1.jpg',
    [[0,1,2], [1,2,3], [2,3,4]],
    [[3], [4], [5]]
  ],
  [
    'image_2.jpg',
    [[5,6,7], [6,7,8], [7,8,9]],
    [[8], [9], [10]]
  ],
  ...
]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train)

# Use map to load the numpy files in parallel
dataset = dataset.map(lambda img_name, cap_train, target: tf.numpy_function(
          map_func, [img_name, cap_train, target], [tf.float32, tf.int32, tf.int32]),
          num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

will return `ValueError: Can't convert Python sequence with mixed types to Tensor.` I guess that's related to the fact that each element in the dataset is of the form `[image, list of integers, list of integers]` but I'm mapping that using `tf.float32, tf.int32, tf.int32` which doesn't take the nested list into consideration.

How should I modify the `dataset.map()` method in order to work with the above `train` dataset?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Any guides or tutorials?

Comment: Yes and yes. I'm trying to follow the tutorial on https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/image_captioning but with some changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `from_generator()`

```
def map_func(img_name, cap_train, target):
  img_tensor = np.load(img_name.decode('ascii')+'.npy').astype(np.float32)
  return img_tensor, cap_train, target


def gen():

  train = [
    [
      'image_1.jpg',
      [[0,1,2], [1,2,3], [2,3,4]],
      [[3], [4], [5]]
    ],
    [
      'image_2.jpg',
      [[5,6,7], [6,7,8], [7,8,9]],
      [[8], [9], [10]]
    ],

  ]  
  for item in train:
    yield item[0], item[1], item[2]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, (tf.string, tf.int32, tf.int32))#, (tf.TensorShape([]), tf.TensorShape([3,3]), tf.TensorShape([3,1])))

# Use map to load the numpy files in parallel
dataset = dataset.map(lambda img_name, cap_train, target: tf.numpy_function(
          map_func, [img_name, cap_train, target], [tf.float32, tf.int32, tf.int32])).batch(1)

for item in iter(dataset):
  print(item)
```

### Edit: Producing batches of data,

```
def map_func(img_name, cap_train, target):  
  img_tensor = np.stack([np.load(img.decode('ascii')+'.npy').astype(np.float32) for img in img_name])
  return img_tensor, cap_train, target


def gen(batch_size):

  train = [
    [
      'image_1.jpg',
      [[0,1,2], [1,2,3], [2,3,4]],
      [[3], [4], [5]]
    ],
    [
      'image_2.jpg',
      [[5,6,7], [6,7,8], [7,8,9]],
      [[8], [9], [10]]
    ],

  ]  
  grp1, grp2, grp3 = zip(*train)
  for i in range(0, len(train), batch_size):
    yield grp1[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size], grp2[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size], grp3[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, (tf.string, tf.int32, tf.int32), 
                                         (tf.TensorShape([None]), tf.TensorShape([None, 3,3]), tf.TensorShape([None, 3,1])), args=[2])

# Use map to load the numpy files in parallel
dataset = dataset.map(lambda img_name, cap_train, target: tf.numpy_function(
          map_func, [img_name, cap_train, target], [tf.float32, tf.int32, tf.int32]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Is there any way to make this work without using batchsize of 1?

Comment: @crash, edited my answer. Unfortunately you cannot use `.batch()` for this purpose